# how to let my reset button work in my countdown?

Tags: javascript, html, button, reset, countdown

```js
// global setinterval timer
let countdownEnded = false;
let intervalSeconds = false;
let counter = -1; // reset  must be counter = -1

// init
(() => {
    updateDisplay(1800, 0);
    document.getElementById('millis').innerHTML = "00";

    //element.addEventListener("click", function(){ myFunction(p1, p2); }); 
})();


function start(time = 1800) {
    let startTime = Date.now();

    let inputTime =
        counter === -1
            ? document.getElementById('minutesInputField').value * 60 || time
            : counter

    intervalSeconds = setInterval(() => {
        let currentTime = Date.now() - startTime;

        if (inputTime < 1) {
            stop();
        } else {
            counter = inputTime - updateDisplay(inputTime, currentTime);
            updateMillis();
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function pause() {
    clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
    interval = undefined;
}

function reset() {
    
}

function stop() {
    let countDivElement = document.getElementById("countdown");
    countDivElement.innerHTML = 'countdown done';
    countdownEnded = true;
    clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
}

function updateDisplay(seconds, currentTime) {
    let timeIncrement = Math.floor(currentTime / 1000);
    updateTime(seconds - timeIncrement);
    return timeIncrement;
}

/**
 * @method - updatesecondsond
 * @summary - This updates the timer every seconds
 */

function updateTime(seconds) {
    let countDivElement = document.getElementById("timer");

    let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
    let remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

    if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = '0' + remainingSeconds;
    }

    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = '0' + minutes;
    }

    if (seconds > 0) {
        seconds = seconds - 1;
    } else {
        stop();
    }

    countDivElement.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + ":";
};

function updateMillis() {
    let countMillsElement = document.getElementById('millis');
    let counterMillis = 99;
    let millis = 0;

    let intervalMillis = setInterval(() => {

        if (counterMillis < 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalMillis);
            counterMillis = 99;
        } else {
            millis = counterMillis < 10 ? counterMillis + '0' : counterMillis;
        };

        countMillsElement.innerHTML = millis;
        counterMillis--;

    }, 10);

    if (countdownEnded) {
        stop();
        clearInterval(intervalMillis);
    }
};
```

```html
 <div class="clock" id="model3">
    <div id="countdown">
      <span id="timer"></span><span id="millis"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="minutesInputField" placeholder="minutes" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn start" onclick="start()">Start</button>
    <button class="btn pause" onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
    <button class="btn reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

  </div>
```

I made a countdown with a start,pause and reset function. The start function works and pause to.
When I press pause and then start it continues so that is perfect.
But if I want to press reset it needs to reset to how many minutes that are put in the input field. And if there is nothing in there because it is on default on 30 minutes it needs to be 30 minutes when you press on the reset button.
That is my problem. If someone can help me out? Thanks!

```
<html>
<div class="clock" id="model3">
    <div id="countdown">
      <span id="timer"></span><span id="millis">

      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="minutesInputField" placeholder="minutes" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn start" onclick="start()">Start</button>
    <button class="btn pause" onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
    <button class="btn reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

  </div>
  </html>




    // global setinterval timer
    let countdownEnded = false;
    let intervalSeconds = false;
    let counter = -1; // reset  must be counter = -1

    // init
    (() => {
        updateDisplay(1800, 0);
        document.getElementById('millis').innerHTML = "00";

        //element.addEventListener("click", function(){ myFunction(p1, p2); }); 
    })();

    function start(time = 1800) {
        let startTime = Date.now();

        let inputTime =
            counter === -1
                ? document.getElementById('minutesInputField').value * 60 || time
                : counter

        intervalSeconds = setInterval(() => {
            let currentTime = Date.now() - startTime;

            if (inputTime < 1) {
                stop();
            } else {
                counter = inputTime - updateDisplay(inputTime, currentTime);
                updateMillis();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function pause() {
        clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
        interval = undefined;
    }

    function reset() {
        clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
        document.getElementById('minutesInputField').innerHTML;
    }

    function stop() {
        let countDivElement = document.getElementById("countdown");
        countDivElement.innerHTML = 'countdown done';
        countdownEnded = true;
        clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
    }

    function updateDisplay(seconds, currentTime) {
        let timeIncrement = Math.floor(currentTime / 1000);
        updateTime(seconds - timeIncrement);
        return timeIncrement;
    }

    /**
     * @method - updatesecondsond
     * @summary - This updates the timer every seconds
     */

    function updateTime(seconds) {
        let countDivElement = document.getElementById("timer");

        let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        let remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = '0' + remainingSeconds;
        }

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }

        if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds = seconds - 1;
        } else {
            stop();
        }

        countDivElement.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + ":";
    };

    function updateMillis() {
        let countMillsElement = document.getElementById('millis');
        let counterMillis = 99;
        let millis = 0;

        let intervalMillis = setInterval(() => {

            if (counterMillis < 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalMillis);
                counterMillis = 99;
            } else {
                millis = counterMillis < 10 ? counterMillis + '0' : counterMillis;
            };

            countMillsElement.innerHTML = millis;
            counterMillis--;

        }, 10);

        if (countdownEnded) {
            stop();
            clearInterval(intervalMillis);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Your reset function is not complete, it must contain something like:

```js
document.getElementById('minutesInputField').innerHTML = '30:00:00';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    function reset() {
        clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
        updateDisplay(document.getElementById('minutesInputField').value*60,0);
    }
```

or this (with default value) :

```
    function reset() {
        defaultMinute = 30;
        clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
        updateDisplay((document.getElementById('minutesInputField').value || defaultMinute)*60,0);
    }
```

```js
// global setinterval timer
    let countdownEnded = false;
    let intervalSeconds = false;
    let counter = -1; // reset  must be counter = -1

    // init
    (() => {
        updateDisplay(1800, 0);
        document.getElementById('millis').innerHTML = "00";

        //element.addEventListener("click", function(){ myFunction(p1, p2); }); 
    })();

    function start(time = 1800) {
        let startTime = Date.now();

        let inputTime =
            counter === -1
                ? document.getElementById('minutesInputField').value * 60 || time
                : counter

        intervalSeconds = setInterval(() => {
            let currentTime = Date.now() - startTime;

            if (inputTime < 1) {
                stop();
            } else {
                counter = inputTime - updateDisplay(inputTime, currentTime);
                updateMillis();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    function pause() {
        clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
        interval = undefined;
    }

    function reset() {
    defaultMinute = 30;
            clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
            updateDisplay((document.getElementById('minutesInputField').value || defaultMinute)*60,0);
        }

    function stop() {
        let countDivElement = document.getElementById("countdown");
        countDivElement.innerHTML = 'countdown done';
        countdownEnded = true;
        clearInterval(intervalSeconds);
    }

    function updateDisplay(seconds, currentTime) {
        let timeIncrement = Math.floor(currentTime / 1000);
        updateTime(seconds - timeIncrement);
        return timeIncrement;
    }

    /**
     * @method - updatesecondsond
     * @summary - This updates the timer every seconds
     */

    function updateTime(seconds) {
        let countDivElement = document.getElementById("timer");

        let minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);
        let remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
            remainingSeconds = '0' + remainingSeconds;
        }

        if (minutes < 10) {
            minutes = '0' + minutes;
        }

        if (seconds > 0) {
            seconds = seconds - 1;
        } else {
            stop();
        }

        countDivElement.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + remainingSeconds + ":";
    };

    function updateMillis() {
        let countMillsElement = document.getElementById('millis');
        let counterMillis = 99;
        let millis = 0;

        let intervalMillis = setInterval(() => {

            if (counterMillis < 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalMillis);
                counterMillis = 99;
            } else {
                millis = counterMillis < 10 ? counterMillis + '0' : counterMillis;
            };

            countMillsElement.innerHTML = millis;
            counterMillis--;

        }, 10);

        if (countdownEnded) {
            stop();
            clearInterval(intervalMillis);
        }
    };
```

```html
<html>
<div class="clock" id="model3">
    <div id="countdown">
      <span id="timer"></span><span id="millis">

      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="number" id="minutesInputField" placeholder="minutes" />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="btn start" onclick="start()">Start</button>
    <button class="btn pause" onclick="pause()">Pause</button>
    <button class="btn reset" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>

  </div>
  </html>
```